# БД ФИАС импорт xml в Postgres

Tags: java, xml, postgresql

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь сделать загрузку данных ФИАС из XML в Postgres, делаю все 
[как написано здесь](http://wiki.gis-lab.info/w/%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%90%D0%A1)

Сгенерировал базу и пытаюсь загрузить данные:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl> 
<connection id = "in" driver="janino"/>
<connection id = "out"
    driver="scriptella.driver.postgresql.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:32768/postgres" 
    schema="fias"
    user="postgres"
    password="postgres">
    autocommit.size=100
</connection>

<query connection-id="in">
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
                        boolean isObject = false;
int nodeCnt = 0;
int recordCnt = 0;
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attr) throws SAXException
{
String names = "";
String values = "";
System.out.print("\rnames: " + names);

                        if (nodeCnt &lt; 1) 
    {    // skip first node
    nodeCnt++;
} else {


    int attrCnt = attr.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i & lt; attrCnt; i++) {


        names += attr.getQName(i) + ",";
        values += "'" + attr.getValue(i).replaceAll("'", "''") + "',";

        System.out.print("\rnames: " + names);
    }

    names = names.substring(0, names.length() - 1);
    values = values.substring(0, values.length() - 1);
    set("sql_names", names);
    set("sql_values", values);
                            < script connection - id = "out" >
                                 INSERT INTO addrobj($sql_names) VALUES($sql_values);
                            </ script >
                            next();

    recordCnt++;
    System.out.print("\rprocessed: " + recordCnt);
}
}
};
System.out.println("\n\n\nConverting...");
saxParser.parse("C:\Users\dvpro\Downloads\fias_xml\AS_ADDROBJ_20180607_3c59c5c3-e827-455f-a8dd-32eb9d8f92d6.XML", handler);
</query>
</etl>
```

И при запуске скрипта получаю:

> PS C:\sql\scriptella-1.1\bin> .\scriptella.bat

```
12.06.2018 21:05:49 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initializing properties: 1%
12.06.2018 21:05:50 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initialized connection id=in, JaninoConnection, Dialect{ Janino 2.56}, properties {}: 3%
12.06.2018 21:05:50 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initialized connection id =out, JdbcConnection{ org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection}, Dialect{PostgreSQL 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1)}, properties {autocommit.size=100}: 5%
12.06.2018 21:05:50 <INFO> Execution Progress./etl/query[1] prepared: 10%
12.06.2018 21:05:50 <INFO> Registered JMX mbean: scriptella:type= etl, url= "file:/C:/sql/scriptella-1.1/bin/etl.xml"

Converting...
12.06.2018 21:05:50 <WARNING> Unable to rollback transaction for connection JaninoConnection: Transactions are not supported by JaninoConnection
12.06.2018 21:05:50 <SEVERE> Script C:\sql\scriptella-1.1\bin\etl.xml execution failed.
Location: /etl/query[1]
Janino provider exception: Query execution failed due to exception
Error codes: []
Driver exception: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
PS C:\sql\scriptella-1.1\
```

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой? Stacktrace не отображается и не могу найти ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
saxParser.parse("file:/C:/Users/dvpro/Downloads/fias_xml/AS_ADDROBJ_20180607_3c59c5c3-e827-455f-a8dd-32eb9d8f92d6.XML", handler);
```